# How to authenticate using the AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I want to authenticate an Amazon Web Services user each time they use my app. I am developing the app using the AWS SDK for asp.net that will use the AWS-CLI to interact with the AWS API.

I know that a user with an AWS account can setup IAM credentials, is there some way I can use this?

The authentication would need to take place while the application is running which is why the following page is of no use to me!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html

Basically I'm looking for some kind of OAuth to gain access to an AWS user's account when they use my app so that I can perform backups, starting and stopping of servers on behalf on them using the AWS Cli on ASP.NET.

Some kind of endpoint that I could get a response with a access and refresh token from would be ideal. For example [this API](https://developer.servicem8.com/v1.0/docs/authentication) contains lots of detail on exactly how to connect on behalf of a user, whereas AWS doesn't seem to have provided anything like this!

Comment: I'm assuming that you're trying to operate in their AWS account on their behalf. The correct way to do this is for the AWS users to establish cross-account IAM role in their accounts, which your app can then assume to get credentials.

Comment: @jarmod what do you mean by my app can assume credentials? Do you know where I can find documentation on this? Everything I've looked at so far is unclear!

Comment: You should read up on IAM roles (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html). Here is an example of how to delegate access from one account to another: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for as it says I need to own the account, I am actually looking to create an app that users can use to access their aws account resources @jarmod

Comment: It doesn't say you have to own both accounts. In the example they've provided, you own both accounts but they've only done that to make it easy for you to get started with.

Comment: If I understand your application intentions. In order for your application to access resources in another AWS account it would need to Assume a role that has been granted from the other AWS account. You don't need to own the other AWS account, it just needs to give your account access in the Principal of the role trust in the other AWS account.

Comment: Yes that is the intentions for my application @strongjz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try AWS Cognito. I am not entirely sure, what kind of aws services are being accessed but Cognito does allow to expose certain services. Please go through https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation may be out of date. At AWS re:Invent 2017, there was an excellent session called "AWS CLI: 2017 and Beyond" which is [currently available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8IyScUGuGI). The presentation goes into detail about some of the new features, including dynamic credentials for the AWS CLI, and there is a corresponding GitHub repository [awslabs/awsprocesscreds](https://github.com/awslabs/awsprocesscreds) which may have some useful examples.